In Flow, access the DefaultExc values for a HTTP Callout Action
In a flow, we are making HTTP Callouts to a middleware layer to sync values to an external system. We set the HTTP Callout Action with only a 2XX response (this is how we received the definition from the middleware party). Now, whenever the external system returns an error, the middleware responds with a 400, and the exact response body is provided. However, due to how Flow works, apparently, referencing the 2XX object returns null values when the status code is not in the 200 range.
The weird thing is, though, that Flow does show the response in the debug views, but does not allow us to access this response (see the picture). The error body is then defined as defaultExc. Does anyone know how to either access the values in defaultExc, or how to update the definition without a full rebuild of the flow on all current environments?

Details: The Flow does a POST to a middleware service. The response is then passed to a decision split to identify whether this was a successful call or not. In all situations the response looks like below. When an error is provided this is set in the error.ErrorId property.
{
"success": true/false,
"message": "success",
"error": {
    // only set on error
    "message": "message if error",
    "id":"MSG0033"
}


Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour.  What you have is a story - a written claim that something doesn't work. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

If you want to receive 4XX, 5XX codes... you need to add these codes to Eternal Services.
You'll see something like this:
"responses": {
      "2XX": {
        "description": "",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "code": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "format": "int64"
                },
                "description": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

You've to add 4xx and/or 5XX:
"responses": {
      "2XX": {...},"4XX": {Same code as 2XX},"5XX": {Same code as 2XX}


I am aware that this is how it should be. But this would require to re-add the external service. So we have to remove it from all referencing flows and readding them. I still have no idea how to properly deploy that.
